# Crosshair like thing showing up in fps game (TF2)

Tags: windows-10, gaming, steam

I installed TF2 today on my PC, and I've been getting a crosshair like image on the top right which is unlickable and unremovable:

[image]

I am not sure where it is coming from, and I don't know how to remove it either.

After I close the game and move to Steam, Steam acts a bit strange with the mouse.

I have tried disabling xbox game bar settings and windows defender settings so far. There seems to be no effect.

This same problem does not happen on any other game I have installed so far.

I have googled "crosshair-like image showing up in game" on google, but to no avail.

I am on Windows 10 Pro on a Lenovo Legion 5i, if that information helps.

Comment: This is a feature of Dolby Atmos.  You can either uninstall it or disable the feature

Comment: Why was this question closed? I know exactly what is causing the crosshair to appear.

Comment: @Ramhound https://www.reddit.com/r/csgo/comments/crm1hi/weird_sound_radar_thing_again/ Apparently this is bloatware installed from lenovo Vantage. Removing Dolby Atmos solved my problem. Apparently it's the sound radar "feature", which can be disabled with Ctrl-Shift-O.

Comment: @Razetime Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is bloatware installed from Lenovo Vantage, which came along with my laptop. Removing the Dolby Atmos Application solved my problem. Apparently it's the sound radar "feature", which can be disabled with Ctrl-Shift-O, if you don't want to remove the application altogether.

**Source:** https://reddit.com/r/csgo/comments/crm1hi/weird_sound_radar_thing_again